# Problem from Plane Trigonometry (S.L. Loney)

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, applications

Q. A square tower stands upon a horizontal plane. From a point in this plane, from which three of its upper corners are visible, their angular elevations are respectively are 45 ∘ ,60 ∘ , and 45 ∘. Show that the height of the tower is to the breadth of one of its sides as  √6 ( √5 + 1) to 4.

I am not able to imagine the diagram of the situation. Moreover, isn't it that the ratio of height of a square to its breadth is the same as ratio of diagonal to its side i.e. √2/1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742880/help-with-this-trigonometry-problem

Comment: Looks like it's rectangular for it to be possible